# two psframe at same height using pstricks

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to create two psframes at same height using the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psframe(-3,-1)(5.5,3) %frame1
\psframe(5.5,-1)(14,3) %frame2
\end{document}
```

given that Y coordinates are same still I can't get them at same height.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Your minimal example produces this output:

[image: frames]

The frames have the same height. Perhaps your previewer has a problem with displaying the output. Try another one, look at the PostScript output and perhaps the PDF version. DVI viewer often don't show the correct PostScript output.